# String to string EXC_BAD_ACCESS why?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, exc-bad-access

whats I missed?

```
NSString * configPath = nil;
-(IBAction)setPlistPathAndWriteData:(id)sender{   
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setDirectory:@"/Volumes/"];
    [panel setNameFieldStringValue:@"config.plist"];
    [panel setRequiredFileType:@"plist"];
    NSInteger ret = [panel runModal];

    if ( ret == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton ) {
        NSString *filePath= [[panel URL] path];
        // with this works fine
        //configPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Volumes/Macintosh HD/config.plist"];
        // with this EXC BAD ACCESS
        configPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filePath];
        [self writeData];
    }
}

-(void)writeData {
    SET_TEMP_PLIST
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
    NSFileHandle *writeHandle = [pipe fileHandleForWriting];
    NSData *configData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:tmpPlist format:
                            NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/libexec/authopen"];
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE////////
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", @"-w", configPath, nil]];
    [task setStandardInput:pipe];
    [writeHandle writeData:configData];
    [task launch];
    close([writeHandle fileDescriptor]);
    [task waitUntilExit];
    [task release];
}
```

**EDIT**

well... works fine with this code:

```
NSString *filePath= [[[panel URL] path] retain];
const char * cString = [filePath UTF8String];
configPath = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cString] retain];
```

but this is not perfect method.. thought

Comment: You've already tagged the question "cocoa" - why tag the subject too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app crashes likely because `configPath` is `nil`, and later in `writeData` you try to initialize a new array with `nil` as the third object :

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", @"-w", configPath, nil]
//                                          ^^^ this is nil
```

I suggest you copy the string returned by `path` :

```
if(ret == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton ) {
    // you become the owner of the string,
    // don't forget to release configPath later
    configPath = [[[panel URL] path] copy];
    [self writeData];
}
```

This may run without any problem.

Comment: Also, in order to not leak the object, you must release it in both `writeData` (after using it) and `dealloc`. In `writeData`, you should replace the object with `nil` in the variable so that you don't get the same crash again when you send `release` to whatever's in the variable in `dealloc`.